# PHP (Zend Framework) Code Profiling on Rackspace Cloud Sites

Tags: php, zend-framework, profiling, rackspace-cloud

I have an application written on top of the Zend Framework that is hosted on Rackspace Cloud Sites.  I want to be able to do code profiling, but I don't know where to begin.  The code profiling tools I've seen require installation on the server.

I already use `Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug` for query profiling, and would like something similar for code profiling.  What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To profile a program, you irremediably need another program loaded in memory, so there is no way to do it "outside".

[Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) or Zend Debugger allows you to profile your code, and you can set it up to use it remotely, but you still need to install it your server.

You can also take a look at [APD](http://en.php.net/apd) (stands for Advanded PHP Debugger) which is part of the PECL.

You could find workaround, or 'PHP' solution, but neither would be accurate or valuable I think.

Anyway, you should not install such tools on live server, however, you can easily install Xdebug through PEAR on your development environment.

The result doesn't need to be accurate, the proportion *should* remains the same, whatever the env you use.

It doesn't matter if your server is I7 Core Xeon 6Ghz or whatever, and your development server is an old Cyrix K6, when there are bottlenecks, they'll be here and there.

Comment: I guess I'll need a server that I can install software on.

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug , you may have tried [zfdebug](http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/).

What about [xhprofile](https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof#readme) ? I have not used, but may be good to try :)